Movie about a couple doing calculations to open a door to another world
My mom told me that she watched a movie a couple years ago (maybe 4 years) in it, a guy (medium size, brown hair) and a girl (normal size and medium length brown hair) work in a company. 
They were contracted by this company to do some kind of calculations. My mom does not remember what was about, but those calculations opened a door to another world. But it was like, they put their hand to a glass (maybe some kind of transparent wall) and with the calculations they were able to go to the other side. The other side looked like an office, a long office. 
At the end, the guy did not get the girl, apparently the girl was very involved with the company or something like that. 
At the beginning, the guy and girl didn't like each other, but then eventually they did. 
Any ideas? It is not the movie Upside Down.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I am not sure but i feel you may be talking about "The Adjustment Bureau".

Just as he is on the brink of winning a Senate seat, politician
  David Norris (Matt Damon) meets a ballerina named Elise Sellas (Emily
  Blunt). Though David is instantly smitten, mysterious men conspire to
  keep him away from the beautiful dancer. David learns that he is
  facing the powerful agents of Fate itself, and glimpsing the future
  laid out for him, must either accept a predetermined path that does
  not include Elise or else defy Fate to be with her.

The only reason I state this movie is because I also in a similiar situation like your mother watched this back one night during my college days and forgot about it, i asked my friends about it but what all i said didn't ring any bells, the one thing i said to him was door led to another place,then he told me about this movie , so if this is the one do let me know.

Some of what the OP said reminded me of that movie as well. But judging by all other details, I don't think it is.

I know , the things listed are very different from it, but the only reason i listed this movie was cos I had told  totally different things to my friend as to what i thought was in this movie, but in everything i said only the door part was the right thing, from which my friend told me about this, which is why i posted that as an answer, @Anto, is this the one?

no, is not The Adjustment Bureau. The actors are younger. They work together in the company, she looks uptight. She believes is what the organization is doing.

ohhh ok. let me check again.

im still looking for this.. any ideas?
